# the application data folder for visual studio cannot be created

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

After I deleted some files from my system to save space on my hard disk,
I face the following problem each time i click on any project .exe

> the application data folder for visual studio cannot be created

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if these steps fix your problem ([taken from a blog article by Aaron Stebner](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/11/08/how-to-fix-application-data-folder-error-when-launching-visual-studio-2005-on-windows-vista.aspx)):

1. Click on the Start menu, choose All Programs, then Accessories
2. Right-click on the item named Command Prompt and choose Run as administrator
3. Click continue to launch an elevated command prompt
4. Run `"%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup`

The above instructions are for VS2005 - you may need to adjust the path in the last line depending on the version of VS you're using (VS2008 = "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0", etc.). Also, if you've installed an Express version of Visual Studio, the .exe might have a different name such as `VCExpress.exe` or `VWDExpress.exe`.

Comment: is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file..

Comment: Exactly what version of Visual Studio and Windows are you dealing with?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 ,, windows 7

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit version of Windows, "%programfiles%" should be "%programfiles(x86)%".  Basically, you need to get the path to wherever VS is installed on your system. You can get this from the property page of the Visual Studio icon if you like, or you can get it by poking around in Explorer.

Comment: OK, then right click on that VS icon and click on "Properties". Look at what's in the "Target" field - that's the command you should use in step #4 with the `/setup` switch.

Comment: @MichaelBurr   using the visual c# 2010 express . command worked but ERROR still there  :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Windows 7 64bit. AMD Phenom II X6 1090T clocked at 3,75Ghz. 12GB DDR3 RAM installed with an ATI Radeon HD 5870 1GB. I'm full Admin on my monster pc. I just installed MS Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition. I see no icons, no start menu changes, nothing. Locating the main exe (devenv.exe) gives me an error. "The Application Data Folder For Visual Studio Cannot Be Created". I have been searching on my computer for the cause. Finally I changed the UAC slider to the bottom (disabled). BOOM!
No error anymore, no weird messages, and the MS Visual Studio 2008 launched. For all the people on the internet that has also encountered this little nightmare, here is the solution. Disable UAC.

Answer (score 1):

I've been going round in circles for a few days getting this while trying to install the DotNet MicroFramework 4.1 with VS2010 on Win7 Ultimate x64. None of the various blogs/articles had a solution that worked for me.

Using sysinternals procmon.exe, I was able to monitor the devenv.exe instance being fired up from the msi with the /setup parameter the same as the answer here indicates.

Turned out to be a permissions problem for nt authority\system on the profile folder c:\users{username}\local\microsoft\visualstudio\10.0. For some unknown reason, the ntfs permissions had an inheritance break on the visualstudio folder and the system account had no access. Fixing the inheritance allowed the install to properly complete.

I know this isn't your specific problem, but every other google query I was running always had this page listed, so it's more for reference for anyone else who happens to stumble by.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was also facing the same issue after installing the VS2005. By opening VS2005 as "Run as administrator", the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019: For us it was a network redirected AppData/Roaming issue. The solution was to manually create the folder …\AppData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ba_xxxxxx
To get the exact folder name to create, use procmon.exe to see why "devenv /setup" is failing.
Change the PROCMON filter to only INCLUDE ProcessName=devenv.exe and EXCLUDE where Result=SUCCESS. Towards the bottom of the filter results you will see a CreateFile that fails.