# Error: The Application Data folder for Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express could not be created

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

Windows 7 Home Premium 64.

After install of VB Express 2010 I get this error when trying to open the application: "The Application Data folder for Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express could not be created".  The most commonly suggested solution to this issue is fixing the User Shell Folders keys in the registry. I checked these and they are correct. I even ran the Fixit to make sure. [KB 886549](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886549/en-us)

Another common solution is to run this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vbexpress.exe" /setup . Running this only gives me the same error.

My administrator account and system both have full control rights to the %APPDATA%\Microsoft directory

I tried uninstalling VBexpress and SQL and removing all registry entries using Registry Workshop and reinstalling vbexpress. Same results.

Next I ran Procmon and filtered for vbexpress.exe. I see 234 events that have NAME NOT FOUND as the result. But I'm not sure what to do with this information. I don't know why this started all of a sudden. I was using VBExpress for months before this happened out of the blue. The second answer of this question seems similar to what I'm experiencing but it doesn't give enough info to help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577623/the-application-data-folder-for-visual-studio-cannot-be-created

Is it a permissions thing?

Here are a few of the events

```
    <event>
<ProcessIndex>108</ProcessIndex>
<Time_of_Day>9:55:23.7394209 PM</Time_of_Day>
<Process_Name>vbexpress.exe</Process_Name>
<PID>5940</PID>
<Operation>RegQueryValue</Operation>
<Path>HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SESSION MANAGER\CWDIllegalInDLLSearch</Path>
<Result>NAME NOT FOUND</Result>
<Detail>Length: 1,024</Detail>
</event>

<event>
<ProcessIndex>108</ProcessIndex>
<Time_of_Day>9:55:23.7369804 PM</Time_of_Day>
<Process_Name>vbexpress.exe</Process_Name>
<PID>5940</PID>
<Operation>RegQueryValue</Operation>
<Path>HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SESSION MANAGER\CWDIllegalInDLLSearch</Path>
<Result>NAME NOT FOUND</Result>
<Detail>Length: 1,024</Detail>
</event>

<event>
<ProcessIndex>108</ProcessIndex>
<Time_of_Day>9:55:23.7386163 PM</Time_of_Day>
<Process_Name>vbexpress.exe</Process_Name>
<PID>5940</PID>
<Operation>RegOpenKey</Operation>
<Path>HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WOW64</Path>
<Result>NAME NOT FOUND</Result>
<Detail>Desired Access: Query Value</Detail>
</event>

<event>
<ProcessIndex>108</ProcessIndex>
<Time_of_Day>9:55:23.7387690 PM</Time_of_Day>
<Process_Name>vbexpress.exe</Process_Name>
<PID>5940</PID>
<Operation>IRP_MJ_CREATE</Operation>
<Path>C:\Windows\System32\wow64log.dll</Path>
<Result>NAME NOT FOUND</Result>
<Detail>Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a</Detail>
</event>

enter code here
```

Comment: Well i gave up after pulling my hair out for a couple weeks and finally re-installed Windows. Still no clue how it all began. I have a sneaking suspicion it had something to do with a Windows update but I can't prove it.

Comment: i ran into a similar problem.The question is old but if you remember ,did you keep your UAC off ?

Comment: No, I turned UAC back on after re-installing Windows. I ended up finding out after having to install Windows several times that I had a back memory module that was causing all kinds of weird issues including, I think, this one.